# GPU support in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, gpu, google-cloud-platform

Does Microsoft Azure offer GPU support?
I know that the N-series was announced some time ago. When are they going to be available to the general Public for use? 
Also, does any of the other architectures offer GPU support?

Comment: There is an open Feature request [1] on the Google Cloud Platform that you can star so you can receive updates about it. [1]: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=14

Answer (score 0):

AWS already offers strong GPU machines for quite a while. Azure GPU machines, which will be stronger than AWS's, are expected to be available to public around Oct, and are already available in private preview for some customers.